# Dropping attributes in item that are None in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a website. I am extracting 5 items from the page. Following is my file

**items.py**

```
class ParseItem(scrapy.Item):
    a = scrapy.Field()
    b = scrapy.Field()
    c = scrapy.Field()
    d = scrapy.Field()
    e = scrapy.Field()
```

I am parsing the data in spiders directory in and this is the function I am using

**parser.py**

```
def parse_page(self, response):
     item = ParseItem()
     item['a'] = response.url
     item['b'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['c'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['d'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['e'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
```

I want to ignore all the fields that return `None`. One approach is to use following

```
tmp1 = response.url

if tmp1 is not None:
    item['a'] = tmp1

tmp2 = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()

if tmp2 is not None:
    item['b'] = tmp2

... and so on
```

But this will become messy if the number of fields increases. What is the best way to handle this in scrapy?

Comment: I would keep `None` (or empty string) in item because it good information about data on page. And more logic if you keep it in CSV or database which need all data in every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use `Item` class then use this class

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Item, Field

class DynamicItem(Item):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._values[key] = value
        self.fields[key] = {}
```

Then in your spider import this

```
from your_project.items import DynamicItem
```

And this is how you `yield`

```
yield DynamicItem(item1= item1_value, item2= item2_value)
```

or more easier in your case

```
 item = {}
 item['a'] = response.url
 item['b'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
 item['c'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
 item['d'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
 item['e'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()

 item_to_yield = {}
 for k, v in item.iteritem():
     if v is not None:
         item_to_yield[k] = item[k]
 yield DynamicItem(**item_to_yield)
```

Comment: `for k, v in item.items():
            if v is None:
                del item[k]`

i used this in python3.x.. its working fine but i think its losing the multi threaded capability

Comment: @Samir How that can lose multi threaded capability :P ... our code is so VERY simple ... just a for loop

Comment: it seems so.. also i keep getting runtime error `dictionary changed size during iteration`.. i am using `items` instead of `iteritem`

Comment: @Samir Hmm, see my updated code, Python is right, dictionary size is changed in the loop when we use `del item[k]` ...

Comment: i was doing the same.. instead of assigning it to another dictionary i was assigning it to item class object

Comment: yeah.. this is also working.. but there seems to be no need to create another dictionary and then pass it to items class just to copy the same data there..

Comment: `dataDict = dict(); dataDict['a'] = response.url; item = ParseItem();         for key in dataDict:
            if dataDict[key] is not None:
                item[key] = dataDict[key]`

Answer (score 0):

I will always discourage using `Item` class, I never used that. Instead just use a Python dictionary.

```
def parse_page(self, response):
     item = {}
     item['a'] = response.url
     item['b'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['c'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['d'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()
     item['e'] = response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='title']/text()").extract_first()

     for k, v in item.iteritem():
         if v is None:
             del item[k]
     yield item
```

Comment: is there any specific reason for not using `Item` class?

Comment: @Samir the only reason is THERE IS NOT PURPOSE/BENEFIT of using Item class, I have been developing scrapers using Python Scrapy for past 4-5 years, I used Item class in the beginning while I was learning Scrapy, and then stopped using, and after that, never felt like need to be using that!

Comment: so if I have to use Item class only, is it possible to do what I asked?

Comment: @Samir see my another answer